# Cannot reset reactive form that contains a select

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 6

My html is

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" >
  <label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" required autofocus >
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="drop" formControlName="drop">
      <option value="developer"selected >developer</option>
      <option value="designer">designer</option>
      <option value="admin">admin</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</form>
```

Even though I set `selected` in the "developer" `option` when the page first loads, the "developer" is not selected. I guess that this is a small bug of angular that cannot render the html right, so I put in my component, as I define the form :

```
  myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name:['',Validators.required],
    drop:['developer']
  });
```

and it works.

What is really weird is that when I do `this.myForm.reset();` inside another button, placed outside the form, the "name" is empty as it should be, but the dropdown is also completely empty, just blank, but it should show "developer", right?

That button hides some elements and should reset the form, it is outside the form and it does

```
  getOtherData(id){
    this.myForm.reset();
```

This does not work, so I have to do

```
this.myForm.setValue({
  name: '',
  drop: 'developer'
});
```

in order to actually reset the form. What is going wrong with the `select` combined with the `reset`? I want to use `reset` once and completely reset the form, without "hacks" How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Because that is the standard html markup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is really weird is that when I do `this.myForm.reset()`; inside another button, placed outside the form, the `"name"` is empty as it should be, but the dropdown is also completely empty, just blank, but it should show `"developer"`, right?

No it shouldn't. What happens when we call `reset()`? Most importantly it **sets all your values to `null`**.

In your select, the field you want selected has the value `"developer"`, so this will of course not then be set, as you have just reset the value to `null`, i.e

```
null === 'developer' // false!
```

This is an Angular form, so Angular really doesn't care about the HTML attributes (in this case `selected`), but listens to the form controls and what are going on there. So what you need to do, is to reset the form with the value you want, for that you can give the value on `reset`:

```
this.myForm.reset({
  name: '',
  drop: 'developer'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, very informative comments. I thought that the `selected` attribute is considered by angular while manipulating a form. My logic was "since `required` is considered, then `selected` is also considered". But since this is not the case, then I will reset the form as you suggested

Comment: I understand the confusion, but we are looking at a value here, very different from `required`. It's just the same if you would set the intial value for your formcontrol to 'admin', but expect 'developer' to be chosen since it has the `selected` attribute :) That brings me to the side comment that avoid using `required` in the template also. Set all the validators you need for the form controls, that's why we have validators on form controls! :) But yes, glad I could help, have a nice day and happy coding! :) :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use patch method to reset Form

**setValue()** methods to update all FormControl values.

**patchValue()** method will also set Formcontrol values from a model but only for those which we have mentioned in the model.

```
this.myForm.patchValue({
  name: ''
});
```

If you want to use reset method for specific FormControl values

```
  this.myForm.get('name').reset();
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-with-form

Comment: Yes, but I am asking how can I use `reset` without using the `patchValue` solution

Comment: why would you want to do in that way . there is a different between setValue and patchValue

Answer (score 1):

You can use reset method and pass value at the same time like this.
Note: always compare with null if you are validating object.

```
 this.form.reset({
    name: '',
    drop: [null]
  });
```

[FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)